# Call a function when my timer reaches zero

Tags: javascript

I've got a timer function as follows (which I've just grabbed off a jsfiddle):

```
function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds )
{
    var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

    function returnDate(){
    return Number(new Date);
    }

    function twoDigits( n )
    {
        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
    }

    function updateTimer()
    {
        msLeft = endTime - (returnDate());
        if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
            element.innerHTML = "0:00";
        } else {
            time = new Date( msLeft );
            hours = time.getUTCHours();
            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
            element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() );
            setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
        }
    }

    element = document.getElementById( elementName );
    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
    updateTimer();
}
```

I call the function and set it to countdown to 2 minutes like so:

```
$(".btn-start").click(function(){
 countdown("countdown-2-minutes",2,0);

});
```

I have another element with id `countdown-8-minutes` that I want to start immediately when the timer on `countdown-2-minutes` reaches 0. How should I do this? I suppose an okay way would be to monitor when the html on the first element reads "0:00" but I don't exactly know how to implement that.

Comment: Call the countdown() method when you set the `innerHTML` to `"0:00"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest; First change your `countdown()` function to accept a callback parameter:

```
function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds, callback )
{
    var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

    function returnDate(){
    return Number(new Date);
    }

    function twoDigits( n )
    {
        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
    }

    function updateTimer()
    {
        msLeft = endTime - (returnDate());
        if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
            element.innerHTML = "0:00";
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback.call()
            }
        } else {
            time = new Date( msLeft );
            hours = time.getUTCHours();
            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
            element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() );
            setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
        }
    }

    element = document.getElementById( elementName );
    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
    updateTimer();
}
```

then pass that callback with your initial call:

```
$(".btn-start").click(function(){
    countdown("countdown-2-minutes",2,0, function(){countdown("countdown-8-minutes",8,0);});
});
```

Comment: thanks, that worked great! But what happens if I don't specify a callback? I'm really new to javascript -- will the function still run?

Comment: The callback, if provided and a function, will run as soon as the timer gets to 00:00. The lines: `if (typeof callback === 'function') { callback.call(); }` check if the callback was passed in as a function. If you do not provide the parameter, then `typeof callback` will return 'undefined', if you didn't provide a function that we could call (say you called: `countdown("countdown-8-minutes",8,0,4); // Obviously 4 is not a valid function`, then it would return 'number'), then we do nothing, otherwise, we call it. Semantically, it's like : countdown from 2 minutes, THEN from 8, THEN nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to watch the element's content to know when to start the next timer. In fact you're already reacting to that happening on the line you check  `if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {` in which you can start your next timer.

Once your current timer hits zero you can just start the next one inside that if statement.

Alternatively you can separate your timer logic from your element logic using something like this:

```js
// CountdownTimer object. Give it a length (ms) to count to, a period (ms)
// to loop updates to the callback, and a callback (function(done:bool)) that
// handles update ticks where done=false and the final tick where done=true.

function CountdownTimer(length, period, callback) {
  this.length = length;
  this.period = period;
  this.callback = callback;
  
  // Assert the callback to be a function to avoid messy error handling, and
  // show we noticed in the console.

  if (typeof this.callback !== 'function') {
    console.warn('Callback was not a function.');
    this.callback = function(){};
  }
  
  // Some publically visible variables for time keeping.

  this.startTime = 0;
  this.elapsed = 0;
  this.remaining = length;
  
  // The _loop scope's 'this' is itself. Give it a handle on the CountdownTimer's
  // 'this' so we can reference the variables inside the loop.
  var scope = this;
  
  // Main loop of the countdown timer.

  this._loop = function() {

    // Get the number of milliseconds since the countdown started.
    scope.elapsed = Date.now() - scope.startTime;

    if (scope.elapsed < scope.length) {

      // Keep looping if the countdown is not yet finished.
      scope.remaining = scope.length - scope.elapsed;
      scope.callback(false);

    } else {

      // Finished looping when the countdown hits or passes the target.
      scope.elapsed = scope.length;
      scope.remaining = 0;
      scope.callback(true);
      // Stop the interval timer from looping again.
      clearInterval(scope._t);

    }
  };
}

// This function starts up the CountdownTimer
CountdownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
  this.startTime = Date.now();
  this._t = setInterval(this._loop, this.period);
}

// Our test elements.
var progress2 = document.getElementById('prog-2m');
var progress8 = document.getElementById('prog-8m');
var clockElement = document.getElementById('clock');
var startButton = document.getElementById('start');

// The 2-minute timer.

var m2 = new CountdownTimer(2 * 60 * 1000, 33, function(done) {

  // Calculate the time to display.
  var mins = Math.floor(m2.remaining / 60 / 1000);
  var secs = Math.floor(m2.remaining / 1000) % 60;
  if (secs < 10) secs = '0' + secs;
  clockElement.textContent = mins + ':' + secs;

  if (done) {

    // If we're done, set the timer to show zero and start the next timer.
    clockElement.textContent = '0:00';
    m8.start();

  }

  // Progress bar display update.
  progress2.style.width = (40 * (m2.elapsed / m2.length)) + 'px';
  progress8.style.width = (160 * (m8.elapsed / m8.length)) + 'px';

});

// The 8-minute timer.

var m8 = new CountdownTimer(8 * 60 * 1000, 33, function(done) {

  // Calculate the time to display.
  var mins = Math.floor(m8.remaining / 60 / 1000);
  var secs = Math.floor(m8.remaining / 1000) % 60;
  if (secs < 10) secs = '0' + secs;
  clockElement.textContent = mins + ':' + secs;

  if (done) {

    // Once done, set the timer to zero and display "Done".
    clockElement.textContent = '0:00 Done';
  }

  // Progress bar display update.
  progress2.style.width = (40 * (m2.elapsed / m2.length)) + 'px';
  progress8.style.width = (160 * (m8.elapsed / m8.length)) + 'px';
});

// Start the 2-minute timer when the button is clicked.
startButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  m2.start();
});
```

```css
#progress {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
}
#prog-2m {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #3c9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#prog-8m {
  width: 160px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #c33;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress">
  <div id="prog-2m"></div>
  <div id="prog-8m"></div>
</div>
<div id="clock">0:00</div>
<button id="start">Begin</button>
```

Comment: but that means I call the countdown function inside the countdown function -- so once I start the 8 minute timer and that reaches zero, won't that start the 8 minute timer again?

Comment: I added another solution to my answer where the timer logic is separate from the element handling logic with a bunch of comments. Doing it this way will untangle your behaviours in a way that makes more sense, and you can re-use the timer behaviour elsewhere wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `countdown()` with the proper parameters when you detect that the timer is finished. Try this:

```
if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
    element.innerHTML = "0:00";
    countdown("countdown-8-minutes",8,0);
}
```

Comment: that's what I thought of at first! But won't that call countdown("countdown-8-minutes",8,0); over and over again? I just want the 8 minute countdown to run once. 

EDIT: and also, I was planning on calling another function after the 8 minute countdown completes.